# Why can't I use C routines to load files in Android NDK?

Tags: android, opengl-es2, ndk

I have successfully rendered a triangle with a hard coded shader using `NativeActivity` of Android NDK. Now I have the requirement to load a shader file. I tried to use `fopen` but it is returning NULL.

I have researched a little bit and found out there's an `AAssetManager` which I can use.  I want to know why `fopen` didn't work and why should I use `AAssetManager` to load files?

Comment: fopen returns NULL if it can't open the file, probably because you just have the path to it incorrect.

Comment: Ya that' correct. But I am pretty sure that's not the issue because I have tried all the possible paths.